# Jenkins CI and performance on slaves

Tags: performance, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, vmware

We just started using Jenkins for continuous intergration. The code is pulled from Perforce. We have one jenkins master (Windows VM) and 3 slaves (Windows VMs). I am more the VMware admin than a programmer.

I have been trying to tweak more and more the Jenkins slave setup. Now they are configured as 16vCPUs + 48GB of RAM per slave. Each time during a build, the CPU is always spiking at 100%. We are closing the build in 2h20m but the goal is to reach 1hr.

What is the best way to do so? What type of tweaks in VMware? How can we push through the build faster?

Thanks!

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing what your builds are doing.

Comment: Agree with @gareth_bowles . I woud say throw more resources at it, but still need to know what you are doing. Jenkins is more of controller to your process the speed of which is entirely up to you. You could break your process down and use multiple executors in some cases where concurrency is allowed - Need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it parallel if possible...
[Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)

The beauty of this is that you can trigger [parametrized](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) or regular.

So your master can start the process and the three slaves will make sure isolated steps are accomplished.

This may give a better view.[image: parallel build]